# Firefox 21 and Ember.js not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, ember.js, mozilla

After Firefox auto-upgraded to v21, it does not allow the ember.js elements in our app to function. We get this error in the Firefox console when the JavaScript tries to load the ember template:

`Error: Permission denied to access property '__ember1370634036480_meta'`

Everything works fine in Chrome and Safari, but its only the new version of Firefox that raises this particular error. It's been really hard to diagnose the exact issue, but any predictions, leads, and guesses are welcome as I'm now desperate to get this fixed!

Comment: it looks like a cross domain access error

Comment: @Eru any idea how a cross domain access error would relate to ember?

Comment: do you have any video or iframe linking to other domain?

Comment: I'm facing he same problem, and i dont have any Iframe linking to other domain.

Comment: @Eru no i don't have any iframe linking to another domain, it seems to be something with ember.

Comment: @guleria are you also using ember.js?

Comment: @ramz15 Yes ember rc 5 version

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Firefox 21 issue and has been fixed with release 22. Please upgrade ASAP.
The only problem is getting your users to upgrade :/